# select records with Count, Sum and Sub-Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql

I need to select all links from the links table whose statistics are not zero:

```
Table tlink: 
    linkid, linkname, userid

Table tuser: 
    userid, username

Table tfact: 
    factid, factorder, userid

Table tstat: 
    statid, linkid, userid
```

The User in tuser orders Clicks which are recorded in tfact.

The User can create several links which are recorded in tlink.

Every click on any Link is recorded in tstat.

The web-page should filter all links whose ordered clicks are used.

EG Company ABC orders 3 times 100 clicks each, making a total of 300 clicks.

Then they create several Links which are all shown till the total of 300 clicks is used.

I have tried several Queries//Sub-Queries but to no avail and would appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried so far; can you provide the same. Also, try editing your question.

Comment: I have tried many different queries eg SELECT DISTINCT dbo.stat.linkid, COUNT(dbo.stat.statid) AS my_stat, dbo.link.linkid AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.link INNER JOIN
                      dbo.stat ON dbo.link.linkid = dbo.stat.linkid
WHERE     (dbo.stat.userid <
                          (SELECT     SUM(factorder) AS my_order
                            FROM          dbo.fact
                            WHERE      (dbo.link.userid = userid)))
GROUP BY dbo.stat.linkid, dbo.link.linkid but got nowhere!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
    l.linkid,
    l.linkname,
    l.userid,
    u.username,
    f.factorder - s.clickCount AS clicksUnused
FROM
    tlink l
    INNER JOIN tuser u ON u.userid = l.userid
    INNER JOIN tfact f ON f.userid = l.userid
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            linkid,
            userid,
            COUNT(*) AS clickCount
        FROM
            tstat
        GROUP BY
            linkid,
            userid
        ) s ON s.linkid = l.linkid AND s.userid = l.userid
```

Comment: thanks, but it does not take in account the clicks ordered in table tfact which has to be superiot to the clicks statir«tistic in tstat

Comment: @Mike Ok, changed it. But why would you register clicks that aren't ordered?

Comment: The idea of this to select only links which are still available and exclude link whose ordered clicks have been reached. eg you order today 100 a clicks and next week another 200 totaling 300, then you create some links, maybe 3 different ones, but when you have reached your 300 clicks then your links will not been show anymore. Therefore the idea is that this query will only return links which have not reached the total of clicks ordered which are stored in tfact.

Comment: It therefore has to count all clicks ordered by the user in tstat, count all clicks done in tstat and then compare this and select only the links which are below the order.

Comment: @Mike Ok, changed it again, assuming factorder is the ordered/maximum click count. But if you want to group this by linkid, of take click date history into account, then you need another table design.

Comment: Thanks, I am off now but will try this 1st thing in the morning, cheers

Comment: jsut wondering if it would not be easier to structure thi righ away in a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

@NGLN

Hi

I am sorry in not answering earlier but have been away for some days.

I think I got it working OK:

> SELECT L.linkid, F.OrderSum - S.clickCount AS clicksUnused FROM tlink AS L INNER JOIN (SELECT userid, SUM(factorder) AS OrderSum FROM tfact GROUP BY userid) AS F ON F.userid = L.userid INNER JOIN (SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS clickCount FROM tstat GROUP BY userid) AS S ON S.userid = L.userid 
>   --WHERE --  clicksUnused >= 1

only problem now that I can't filter out Links whose clicksUnused are higher than 1.

Any ideas, thanks, Mike

UPDATE Got this working

> WHERE F.OrderSum > S.clickCount

Is this the correct way?